# Converting a String containing text for a Python variable assignment into an actual variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a String containing a Python variable assignment into an actual variable.

The following was working for me.

```
    s = "VAR = [1,55]"
    exec(s)
    print(VAR)
```

But then when places this code in a function, VAR never gets defined.

```
    def myFunction():
        s = "VAR = [1,55]"
        exec(s)
        print(VAR)

    myFunction()
```

I'm not sure what I am missing. Thanks in advance for the help!

Responses to a few of the questions...

Error message: "NameError: name 'VAR' is not defined"

Using: Python 3

Comment: This is usually a really bad idea. Can I ask what you're using this for?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @PeterWood It's "NameError: name 'VAR' is not defined"

Comment: @Brett, you are using Python 3, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also pass globals to exec:

```
def myFunction():
    s = "VAR = [1,55]"
    exec(s, globals())
    print(VAR)
```

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31372469/2141635)

Answer (score 2):

python 2.7

```
def myfunc():
    v1 = 11
    exec "v1 = 22"
    print v1

myfunc() # 22

def myFunction():
    VAR = None
    s = "VAR = [1,55]"
    exec(s)
    print(VAR)

myFunction() # [1, 55]
```

OR

```
def myFunction():
    #VAR = None
    s = "VAR = [1,55]"
    exec(s)
    print(locals()["VAR"])

myFunction() # [1,55]
```

Comment: I suspect the OP is using Python 3, where `exec` is a function.

Comment: Is there any official documentation of this behavior? I noticed that depending whether one uses `VAR` later, `exec` decides on inserting it into `locals()` (perculiar: if one *uses* it, `exec` does *not* insert it into `locals()`)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The OP uses `exec(s)` which is a function call.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7 you can simply do:

```
>> s = "VAR=55"
>> exec(s)
>> VAR
55
```

If you need custom namespace do:

```
>> my_ns = {}
>> exec "VAR=55" in my_ns
>> my_ns["VAR"]
55
```

Similar applies for Python 3 but `exec` there is actually a function so `exec(...)` is to be used. For example:

```
>> s = "VAR=55"
>> exec(s)
>> VAR
55
```

When you use functions scope comes into play. You can use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) or use your custom namespace:

```
>>def foo():
    ns = {}
    s = "VAR=55"
    exec(s) in ns
    print(ns["VAR"])

>>foo()
55
```

Comment: And damn it I type slow! Started typing first and finished last. LOL